# Cant connect to redis in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, redis

Basically I have no idea why node will not connect to redis. I am able to connect to it via the CLI, and below you can see the brew service is started without any errors. I've provided all the needed code and info, let me know if you need anything else.

**Node Error:**

```
(node:6601) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The client is closed
at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (/Users/arialopez/code/url-shortener/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:387:31)
at Commander.commandsExecutor (/Users/arialopez/code/url-shortener/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/client/index.js:160:154)
at Commander.BaseClass.<computed> [as ping] (/Users/arialopez/code/url-shortener/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/commander.js:8:29)
at new AsyncRedis (/Users/arialopez/code/url-shortener/redis/index.js:21:21)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/arialopez/code/url-shortener/lib/models.js:3:15)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
```

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6601) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:6601) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

**Connection Code:**

```
require('dotenv').config();
const redis = require('redis');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const defaultOptions = { // The defaults are being used not env.
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOST || '127.0.0.1',
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT || 6379,
    keyPrefix: process.env.REDIS_PREFIX || 'url-'
};

class AsyncRedis {
    constructor() {
        this.client = redis.createClient(defaultOptions);
        this.client.on('error', this.error); // error handler defind below
        this.client.ping() // WHERE CODE IS BREAKING
    }
    ... Class code
}
```

**Brew Status:**

```
redis             started
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `client.connect()` before executing commands. BTW, `redis@4.0.0` have built-in promises support, there is no need to create an async wrapper

```js
const redis = require('redis'),
  client = redis.createClient({
    // ...
  });

client.on('error', err => {
  // ...
});

await client.connect();
console.log(await client.ping());
```